# PHPMailer issue on ContactForm7

Tags: contact-form-7

I'm getting a fatal error when i try to send a ContactForm7. It's a missing PHPMailer library.

So far I've tried:

1. Installing composer in my public_html as per hostinger's instructions

`composer2 require phpmailer/phpmailer`

phpmailer installs no problem, i still get the fatal error when i try to send a form

2. Installing composer in /public_html/rebelcitytour.com/wp-includes/

phpmailer installs fine, still get error.

3. creating a soft link to resolve the path issue...

```
cd /home/uxxxxxxxx/domains/rebelcitytour.com/public_html/wp-includes/
ln -s /home/uxxxxxx/domains/rebelcitytour.com/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer
```

Composer has installed phpmailer at...

```
path: /home/uxxxxxx/domains/rebelcitytour.com/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer
```

I've also installed and configured one of the WP SMTP mailer plugins. This doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

So, my dev had declared a global SMTP variable in functions.php on WordPress.

I tracked down this issue and fixed it...